# Mouseleave not really being called by IE with color animations

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, coloranimation

I know that there are tons of questions like this on SO, but I haven't been able to find one with animating colors.  On mouse over, it animates to a color (I made it an ugly blue just for testing purposes, and on mouse out, it animates to its original color.  It works perfectly on all other browsers but IE, which animates the mouse over, but doesn't animate the mouse out.

The related js

```
$(".entry").mouseover(function () {

    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"rgba(0,255,255,0.5)"},{duration:300, queue:false});

});

$(".entry").mouseout(function () {

    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"white"},{duration:300, queue:false});

});
```

Comment: Please post your js code for the animation with relative markup and avoidposting a link to a page for us to decode

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory, it's only about 20 lines.

Comment: It doesn't work on 8.  Are you actually on 8, or on IE9 developer tools? I've found that they display differently.

Comment: @KarlWeisshaupt follow guidelines of how to ask and you shall receive the best answers. It works as in when you mouse out, the colour goes back to white but it does not animate to white

Comment: But that's not how I wanted it to be.  That doesn't mean "work".

Comment: If you can create a fiddle, that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/W3PWA/1/

I only converted the backgroundColor to rgba instead of the word white. Since you are using the latest jquery, you should using .on()

```
$(".entry").on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    // your code
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    // your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer, except one thing...why does the animation get faster after the first time you mouse over and out?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the first time and Nth time. If you think it is getting faster then ask it in a different question. Also you might wanna change up the other div hovers, make them more specific targetting. Here is a clean version http://jsfiddle.net/W3PWA/3/

Comment: What do you mean? What's the difference?

Comment: @KarlWeisshaupt on your site, effect.js, you have an event listener on $("div"), I think you are using it for probbaly header or footer. The .entry is also a div, to reduce overhead, you can easily add a class for the header or footer or whatever it is you are targetting. Or target it through a parent id or class